# Angular Mater 2 Normal Input

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-material-5, angular-material-6

Is there a way to achieve a normal inpout biox with angular material 2? such as the image[image]

When ever i refer to the Docs In only see inputs where when click the placeholder text floats up.

Comment: You can also try utlising the native HTML `input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this code in my project 
it is the same as your input but has an underline in the bottom of the input

I just make some changes in `mat-form-field` style

```
<mat-form-field   style="padding:3px;border-radius:60px;border-style:solid; border-color:#c0bfbf91;border-width:1px">
    <input matInput  value="Sushi">
  <mat-icon  matSuffix>search</mat-icon>
      <mat-placeholder style="margin-left:20px">Favorite food</mat-placeholder>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I strongly suggest that you utilise CSS classes instead of inline styles as it's considered a bad practice and may cause code readability problems.

Comment: Yup... I added the solution when I am in working ... thanks for suggest

Answer (score 2):

You can use `floatLabel="never"` on your mat form field:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="legacy" floatLabel="never">
    <mat-label>Search here</mat-label>
    <input matInput>
    <mat-icon matSuffix>search</mat-icon>
</mat-form-field>
```

You cannot combine it with the `appearance="outline"` like in your example image as stated in the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api):

> Note: only the legacy appearance supports the never option. never was originally added as a way to make the floating label emulate the behavior of a standard input placeholder. However the form field now supports both floating labels and placeholders. Therefore in the non-legacy appearances the never option has been disabled in favor of just using the placeholder.

Comment: For a non-floating placeholder with 'outline' style, use `<input matInput placeholder="Search here">` and leave out the `<mat-label>`.